# Python's import and packages (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following the [Python tutorial here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_modules.htm) and I'm trying to test the packages. At this point, I have the following file structure:

```
main.py
Phone/
    __init__.py
    G3.py
    Isdn.py
    Pots.py
```

And here are the file contents:

**main.py**

```
import Phone

Phone.Pots()
Phone.G3()
Phone.Isdn()
```

**__init__.py**

```
from Pots import Pots
from Isdn import Isdn
from G3 import G3
```

And the other three files are just defining some dummy functions. The problem is that when I execute the main.py, I get:

```
$ python3.6 ./main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Phone
  File "/home/mehran/tmp/python-test/Phone/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Pots import Pots
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pots'
```

I understand what the problem is. It's because the Python interpreter is looking for the *Pots* in the parent folder instead of the *Phone* folder. So my question is, how can I make this work?

Comment: try `from Phone.Pots import Pots` in __init__.py

Comment: is `from Pots import *` working for you?

Comment: Use a relative import in the package - `from .Pots import Pots`. Imports are based on which ever module is executed as main, so `from Pots import Pots` is looking for a `Pots.py` at the outer `main.py` scope

Comment: @PeterGibson Thanks, that's my answer. If you please post as an answer, I'll be happy to flag it.

Answer (score 0):

If You have Pots definition inside Pots.py then go for comments in Your question, otherwise You need that name inside a file to import it.